# Can I decompose a Python Flag enum into its fundamental parts?

Tags: python, enums, enum-flags, bitflags

I have an enum that represents the directions you're allowed to move for a given cell in a maze:

```
class Direction(Flag):
    NORTH = 1
    EAST = 2
    SOUTH = 4
    WEST = 8
    NE = NORTH | EAST
    NW = NORTH | WEST
    ...etc
    NESW = NORTH | EAST | SOUTH | WEST
```

This makes it easy to check if you can go west, you can just check `cell.directions & Direction.WEST`.  But what if I want to iterate over the possible directions?  Something like `for d in cell.directions: ...`, but you can't do this.  If I didn't alias every possible combination of directions (which makes things easier in my code), then I could do:

```
for d in Direction:
    if cell.directions & d:
        ....
```

But this won't work for me because it would iterate over all the combined directions too, rather than just the four basic cardinal directions.  Is there a good solution here?

Comment: Why are `NE`, `NW`, etc. included in your enum in the first place? Not sure that makes sense.

Comment: What do you mean by "possible directions"? Does that include NESW?

Comment: @Chris Why not? Is that sort of a deprecated thing to do? It make it easier when setting up the maze to have aliases like that so I don't have to keep doing `Direction.NORTH | Direction.EAST` (part of the maze is hard-coded). I suppose I could just make constants outside of the enum though...

Comment: @codebreaker, "northeast" is a direction, but when you say `NE` I don't think you mean that. You mean "north is available, and east is available". It's not a single direction. A set of available directions is fundamentally different from a single direction.

Comment: @Chris that's fair. Maybe the name of my class/constants is misleading, but I still don't see why it's bad practice to alias these groups.

Comment: @codebreaker, just not how I'd approach it. Ethan's answer about Python 3.11 is very interesting, I didn't realize Python would be that clever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3.11 this works as you would expect:  iteration only provides the canonical (i.e. powers of two) flags, all others are considered aliases.

Even in prior versions, though, this works:

```
from enum import Flag

class Direction(Flag):
    NORTH = 1
    EAST = 2
    SOUTH = 4
    WEST = 8

NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST = Direction

directions = NORTH | EAST
d = NORTH
if d in directions:
    print('going North!')
```

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Wow, that's great. I guess this is what I get for putting off updating to 3.11. This does not work for me in 3.10 though!

Comment: @codebreaker: I fixed the typo in my code, and made sure the example will run. Are you still having difficulties?  Of so, what's the error?

Comment: Sorry, the code example looks like it would work in 3.10.  I thought you were saying iteration on a Flag would work in earlier versions.

Comment: @codebreaker: Iteration does work on Flags, and has since they were introduced in 3.6.  Prior to 3.11 you would also get the aliases when iterating.

Comment: Right, I did just notice that I wasn't getting the aliases anymore if I did `list(Direction)`. But what I meant by "iteration on a Flag" was `list(Direction.NW)` now works and gives me `[Direction.NORTH, Direction.WEST]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a list `basic_directions = [NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST]` and use the same for loop that you wrote before:

```
for d in basic_directions:
    if cell.directions & d:
        ....
```

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing but it feels like I'm violating DRY.